# How to calculate Heuristic values for minimax

Tags: algorithm, heuristics, minimax, calculation

I am developing a software for a board game (2 player) which has 10x4 cells and both the players have 9 pieces each. Initially, the pieces for player 1 will be at the top of the board and for player 2 all the pieces will be at the bottom of the board (similar to chess but a lot less complex!).

I have used MiniMax algorithm to calculate the next best move. Now, the algorithm itself seems to work fine. The problem that I am facing is in Heuristic value calculation.
If there is no best move found in the depth till I am searching (4 currently), my code simply takes the first step which it finds from the move list. That is probably because the score of all the moves are same till the depth of 4!

So, it just keeps stalling. Eg., it will move piece 1 from position A to B in 1st turn and in the 2nd turn it will move the same piece from position B to A.
It keeps on doing that until the opponent moves closer to my pieces.

Now, what I want would love to know is how do I make sure that if the opponent is NOT closing in, I do that instead of stalling.
Currently, I am calculating the heuristic values based on the difference between my pieces and opp pieces.
How to calculate the values such that those moves which lead to position closer to the opponent's pieces are selected? Appreciate your help! Thanks!

Comment: There is a generally good heuristic "the more options, the better" - try to add that with low weight (i.e. add to each position something like 0.01 x (number of possible moves)).

Comment: The specific heuristic might depend on the actual game. You could also try to count the number of pieces or the difference of the number of pieces - the more pieces, the better.

Comment: @Abstraction - Thank you for your response! By adding 0.01 x (number of possible moves), how will it improve the logic to play towards the opponent's pieces? Can you please elaborate?  Thanks!

Comment: @Codor - I am already doing that. (calculating the difference in my pieces and that of the opponent). This logic works great if I am able to capture more number of opponent's piece(s) than I sacrifice my pieces till max depth.
But, If I am not able to capture any opponent piece till max depth, then the score is 0. Now in this case how do I teach my AI to move towards the opponent's pieces? Thank you for help!

Comment: @NisargVarma *If* I understand rules of your game correctly, AI will start spreading his pieces from starting position until "enemy contact"; given board size, this alone should be enough (on bigger board, you may also add "better move forward" heuristic, making your pieces cost slightly bigger the closer they are to an enemy piece)